# How to assign value to ng-model if it is empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to assign value to ng-model if it is empty. I have assign default value to ng-model input from controller but when user makes change to remove that value and makes input empty then I want to assign default value to ng-model.

For example.

Controller:

```
App.controller('mainController',['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.assignOne= 16;
}]);
```

View:

```
<input ng-model="assignOne" ng-change="changeMe()"/>
```

Now, input value becomes 16.

If user make changes and manually removes this value 16 then I want default value 1 instead of empty string in changeMe() function.

Note:
I can check for empty ng-model and override value of ng-model in controller. But, Is there any way better way to use, something which angular provides.

I am just new to AngularJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$watch` as follows

```
$scope.$watch(
   "assignOne",
    function handleChange( newValue, oldValue ) {
          console.log( "assignOne:", newValue );
          if(newValue == '') {
             newValue = 16;
          }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

another solution to meet your sample:

```
App.controller('mainController',['$scope', function($scope) {

   $scope.assignOne= 16;

   // function called by " ... ng-change="changeMe() "
   $scope.changeMe = function() {
      if ($scope.assignOne == '') {
          $scope.assignOne = 1;
      }
   }
}]);
```

PS: for the previous answer, there is a little miss: it doesn't change the "assignOne" var, but only a local copy, which is lost at the end of the function call...  Correct it by changing $scope.assignOne !

PS 2: the 2 solutions are good, but can resolve different requirements :

- $watch is like a trigger on the model object, and is the most efficient if you want check business rules on the navigator side
- ng-change is more interesting for handling some interactions, which are not stricts rules...

The 2 ways could be used...

Comment: Explain you answer.[From review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10663763)

Comment: I complete the JS sample